# NuGet packing same dll twice in different folders: Cannot add part for the specified URI because it is already in the package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I have the following two lines in my nuspec which result in the error:

> Cannot add part for the specified URI because it is already in the package.

Here's the code in the nuspec:

```
        <file src="bin\release\*.dll" target="lib" />
        <file src="..\myProj\bin\release\*.dll" target="tools" />
```

Any thoughts on how I can get the same dlls into both targets?  I'm using VSTS to do the nuget packaging.  (I wasn't able to find any similar questions.)